# Why FrameLength is -1?

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I am trying to get the amplitude of one of the mp3 files. Following is the code:

```
        AudioInputStream ain = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        AudioFormat baseFormat = ain.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(
                                        AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                                        baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                                        16,
                                        baseFormat.getChannels(),
                                        baseFormat.getChannels()*2,
                                        baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                                        false);
        //play(file,din,decodedFormat,ain);
        ain = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
        DecodedMpegAudioInputStream decodedStream = new DecodedMpegAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, ain);
        System.out.println(ain.getFrameLength());
        System.out.println(decodedStream.getFrameLength());
```

The problem is the last printlns are returning -1 in other words there is no information of frame length in the mp3 file or the audiostream is unable to read the frame length (is that possible?). I am trying to learn about mp3 audio file format. Am I doing this correct? OR is there any other way to get the frame length?

Comment: If you've decoded the mp3 into raw pcm, then there are no more frames. Frames are an MPEG concept which do not apply to pcm

Comment: Thanks Marc. Even the encoded mp3 file is returning frame length as -1. I have put the first println "System.out.println(ain.getFrameLength());" solely to see whether encoded file has any frame length info or not.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if `AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file)` is an MPEG format and run through its properties

```
AudioFileFormat audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
if (audioFileFormat instanceof TAudioFileFormat) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = ((TAudioFileFormat) audioFileFormat).properties();
// ...
}
```

There's properties like `mp3.length.bytes` and may help